# How user manager in ubuntu adds users from gui

Tags: gnome, gui, adduser

Can anybody describe how user manager in gnome or any other DE adds users without commandline using GUI? How it binds adduser function and GTK together?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question is reading source code.

1. Let's consider `users-admin` executable which is used in Ubuntu MATE.

   It is [a part](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=users-admin) of [`gnome-system-tools` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/gnome-system-tools).

   Its source code is [located on GitHub](https://github.com/LStranger/gnome-system-tools).

   So you have to read source code in the [*users* folder](https://github.com/LStranger/gnome-system-tools/tree/master/src/users) to find what you want to find.
2. Also we can consider `gnome-control-center`'s `user-accounts` applet for GNOME sHell.

   It is [a part](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gnome-control-center/filelist) of [`gnome-control-center` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-control-center).

   Here is [its source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-control-center/1:3.36.1-1/panels/user-accounts/user-utils.c) or better [here](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/gnome-control-center/-/tree/ubuntu/master/panels%2Fuser-accounts). You can read it too.